# newcommand for Zhuyin/Bopomofo tone marks next to Chinese character

Tags: macros, tabularx

I want to place Zhuyin next to enlarged characters in a line of text. I abstracted it down to this (with X representing a Chinese character and A/AB/ABC the Zhuyin:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}

lorem ipsum \raisebox{-2mm}{\Huge X}
\hspace{-2mm}\scalebox{0.8}{
    \begin{tabularx}{1em}{@{}l@{}}
        \textit{A}\\ \textit{B}\\ \textit{C}
    \end{tabularx}}
dolor sit \raisebox{-2mm}{\Huge X}
\hspace{-2mm}\scalebox{0.8}{
    \begin{tabularx}{1em}{@{}l@{}}
        \textit{A}\\
    \end{tabularx}}
amet \raisebox{-2mm}{\Huge X}
\hspace{-2mm}\scalebox{0.8}{
    \begin{tabularx}{1em}{@{}l@{}}
        \textit{A}\\ \textit{B}
    \end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

What I'd like to achieve is replacing this:

```
\hspace{-2mm}\scalebox{0.8}{
    \begin{tabularx}{1em}{@{}l@{}}
        \textit{A}\\ \textit{B}\\ \textit{C}
    \end{tabularx}}
```

by this:

```
\zhuyin{ABC}
```

It is important to notice that the Zhuyin will always be 1, 2 or 3 characters long and I would love to have one single command that can deal with `\zhuyin{A}` and `\zhuyin{AB}` as well instead of 3 separate commands depending on whether it's 1, 2 or 3 characters in length.

It basically comes down to "how do I separate a 1-to-3-char argument into `{1st char}` or `{1st char}\\{2nd char}` or `{1st char}\\{2nd char}\\{3rd char}` depending on the length of the argument".

Treating it as three (or two or one) separate arguments won't work since afaik LaTeX commmands can't be overloaded like functions in many programming languages.

Thanks for your ideas in advance! I really appreciate this community!

Comment: Would a syntax with three arguments of which two are optional be acceptable? Like `\zhuyin{A} lipsum \zhuyin{A}{B}{C} lipsum \zhuyin{A}{B} etc`?

Comment: Yes, it would! I had just assumed it would be impossible to have optional arguments in `\newcommand`s.

Comment: For LaTeX2e (i.e., `\newcommand`) you can have at most 1 optional argument, and it needs to be the first. LaTeX3 (`\NewDocumentCommand`) is more flexible and allows for multiple optional arguments at any position.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

[image]

If the symbols in the column vector to the right of the `\Huge` character are too small for your taste, feel free to replace `\tiny` with `\scriptsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\zhuyin[2]{\begingroup % localize scope of next instruction
                      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.55}%
                      \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\Huge}l@{}} #1 \end{tabular}%
                      \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\tiny\itshape}l@{}} #2 \end{tabular}%
                      \endgroup}

\begin{document}
lorem ipsum \zhuyin{X}{A \\ B \\ C} dolor sit \zhuyin{X}{A} amet \zhuyin{X}{A \\ B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks a lot! I actually just found another way myself, I'll post another answer for future learners.

Answer (score 2):

You could attempt to activate the OpenType vertical-writing features, but `fontspec` does not actually support vertical writing.  It does allow you to select the OpenType `vrt2` feature, which in theory might provide rotated glyphs, and place them in a `\rotatebox`.

However, the following code did not work correctly when I tested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[nil]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\babelprovide[import=zh-hans, main]{chinese} % Or import=zh-hant for Traditional Chinese

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer=HarfBuzz }

\defaultfontfeatures[NotoSerifCJKsc]{
  Ligatures={Common,Discretionary},
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  Extension = .otf}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0]{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[chinese]{rm}
          {NotoSerifCJKsc}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}

\newcommand{\zhuyin}[1]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
    \foreignlanguage{chinese}{%
      \addfontfeature{Vertical={RotatedGlyphs,HalfMetrics,Kerning}}%
      #1}}}

\begin{document}
瓶\zhuyin{ㄆㄧㄥ}子\zhuyin{ㄗ}
\end{document}
```

Specifically, although Noto Serif CJK supports the vertical-layout OpenType features, the *zhuyin* appeared and were rotated in their original forms, and so came out in the wrong orientation.  If you know of a font that provides rotated Unicode *bopomofo*, you might try this solution with that font.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just found the [`xstring`](http://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/generic/xstring/xstring-en.pdf) package which made it pretty easy so in addition to Mico's answer, I could also solve it myself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xstring}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}

\newcommand{\zhuyin}[1]{%
  \StrLen{#1}[\length]%
  \hspace{-0.8mm}\scalebox{0.8}{
  \begin{tabularx}{1em}{@{}>{\itshape}l@{}}
    \ifnum\length=1
      \StrChar{#1}{1}
    \else
      \ifnum\length=2
        \StrChar{#1}{1}\\
        \StrChar{#1}{2}
      \else
        \StrChar{#1}{1}\\
        \StrChar{#1}{2}\\
        \StrChar{#1}{3}
      \fi
    \fi
  \end{tabularx}}
}

\begin{document}

lorem ipsum \raisebox{-2mm}{\Huge X}\zhuyin{ABC}
dolor sit \raisebox{-2mm}{\Huge X}\zhuyin{A}
amet \raisebox{-2mm}{\Huge X}\zhuyin{AB}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

@Mico: Totally correct, `tabular` totally suffices, no need for `tabularx`. I also added another optional argument for the tone mark. This is the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % for Kaiti and Ming (Song)
\usepackage{graphicx} % for scalebox
\usepackage{xstring} % for string slicing in \zhuyin command

\newfontfamily\kaitiTW{TW-Kai-98_1.ttf}

\newcommand{\trad}[1]{{\kaitiTW \large #1}}

\newcommand{\zhuyin}[2][]{%
\smash{
  \StrLen{#2}[\length]%
  \hspace{-3mm}
  \parbox[c][][c]{3mm}{%
  \scalebox{0.45}{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\kaitiTW}l@{}}
      \ifnum\length=1
        \StrChar{#2}{1}%
      \else
        \ifnum\length=2
          \StrChar{#2}{1}\\
          \StrChar{#2}{2}%
        \else
          \StrChar{#2}{1}\\
          \StrChar{#2}{2}\\
          \StrChar{#2}{3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \hspace{-0.7em} \smash{\raisebox{0.7em}{\scalebox{0.6}{\kaitiTW #1}}}
  \end{tabular}}}}
  \hspace{-2mm}
}

\begin{document}

\trad{黑}\zhuyin{ㄏㄟ}\textit{hēi},
\trad{狂}\zhuyin[ˊ]{ㄎㄨㄤ}\textit{kuáng},
\trad{短}\zhuyin[ˇ]{ㄉㄨㄢ}\textit{duǎn},
\trad{鬱}\zhuyin[ˋ]{ㄩ}\textit{yǜ}

\end{document}
```

Obviously has to be compiled with XeLaTeX. Font used can be found [here](https://data.gov.tw/dataset/5961).

[image: output]

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to use a `tabularx` environment for the use case at hand, especially as (a) there is no need for automatic line breaking in the cells, (b) you're not employing a single `X`-type column in the `tabularx` environment, and (c) the target width of `1em` seems excessive. I think a simple `tabular` environment with an `l` column type would be more appropriate.